# set footer height dynamic

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a webpage and need to do something in the footer. Currently, the footer height is fixed. In this case, if the content area is small, it appears a blank area below the footer. But I want to extend the footer background towards the bottom dynamically. You can check the example here: http://jilson.me/stack/index.html

The css code for the footer is:

```
.footer{
    height:64px;
    border-top:5px solid #4b4b4b;
    background:#383838;
    max-width:1400px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

Please let me know if you want more of the code. Thanks in advance.

Comment: set Height:auto; try this

Comment: Didn't work. You can see the effect by zooming out the page.

Comment: ok remove the height from css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply the background color of the footer to the body tag:

```
body{
   background-color:#383838;
}
```

Then move your footer div outside the wrapper div and set the background color of wrapper to

> background-color:#fff;

Answer (score 0):

Add `height:100%` to html

Add this in css

```
html, body{height:100%}
```

Comment: Still not working! You can zoom out the page and see the effect on footer.

Answer (score 0):

See the  link jsfiddle.net/FkPqb/ i hope this will help for u.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ,
apply this css to your footer

```
min-height:64px;
overflow:hidden;
```

hope it ll help.

Comment: Go to mailchimp.com and try to zoom out the page. (Ctrl and -). See how the footer works. I need to make like that!

Comment: apply background-color:#383838; to ur html tag.. as above site